# PHP and OCI8 running subquery on a dataset

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oci8

I'm not sure if I am asking this the correct way, but I want to run a query on an Oracle database, fetch the result, and then run additional queries on that result dataset. Is that possible? I am trying to avoid another call to the database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MY.TABLE "; 
$stid = oci_parse($connection, $query);
oci_execute($stid);
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS_OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) { 
//my code for the full dataset
}
```

Then I would like to do something like

```
PSUEDO-CODE
$newDataset = runThisQuery("SELECT * FROM [oci dataset from above(what is that syntax?)] WHERE my_value = 1");
while($newRow = loop through $newDataset){
//my code for the subquery
}
```

Any suggestions?

To further describe my problem: I am getting a table of fields, and from that table I would like to extract the unique values of certain fields into their own php arrays.

Comment: You can't query a result set like that.  Try to explain your problem instead of your proposed solution. Why do you need to query the result set (or run another query) instead of just manipulating the first result set in PHP?

Comment: @timclutton I have a rather large dataset, and I was hoping there was a SQL way to manipulate the data, rather than doing a time intensive loop in php to extract data.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to send multiple queries?  It seems like you might be [prematurely optimising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  DB servers are designed to handle impressive amounts of queries, and to do it efficiently.

Comment: @timclutton Thank you for that validation. The DB group I am working with has high concern on number of db calls from my software. I will go forward with multiple calls and then revisit the problem if the load testing proves it to be an issue.

Comment: The load will be an issue sooner or later.  Look at SQL statements such as WITH.  The best place to ask is asktom.oracle.com

Comment: The load is definitely an issue.